# Modify docx page margins with python-docx

Tags: python, python-docx

I need to quickly change the margins of many docx documents. I checked python-docx and I do not find a way to access/modify the page layout (in particular the margins) properties. Is there a way?

Comment: Margins are controlled by [Section objects](http://python-docx.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/section.html#sections-objects). See [Working With Sections](http://python-docx.readthedocs.org/en/latest/user/sections.html) for more details. I think you can just enumerate the sections in the doc and change the margin properties.

Comment: Totally true @tdelaney, somehow I has misread this part of the documentation. Thanks for pointing this out!

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Thanks to @tdelaney for pointing out the page where it clearly indicated the solution.
I am just posting here the code I used in case anyone else is confused as I initially was:

```
#Open the document
document = Document(args.inputFile)

#changing the page margins
sections = document.sections
for section in sections:
    section.top_margin = Cm(margin)
    section.bottom_margin = Cm(margin)
    section.left_margin = Cm(margin)
    section.right_margin = Cm(margin)

document.save(args.outputFile)
```

Comment: Is there any method to change the Left and Right margin of only the Header and Footer and NOT the whole page/section?

Comment: @XAnguera what does "Args" means?

Comment: @Steve It's probably the output of `argparse`, which is storing the values passed in from the command line.

Comment: @Anthony What does that mean exactly?

Answer (score 15):

```
import docx
from docx.shared import Inches, Cm
doc = docx.Document()
sections = doc.sections
for section in sections:
    section.top_margin = Cm(0.5)
    section.bottom_margin = Cm(0.5)
    section.left_margin = Cm(1)
    section.right_margin = Cm(1)
```

Here's the code that i used please include **from docx.shared import Inches, Cm**